# Java SSL Socket issues: ServerSocket does not receive data and handshake fails

Tags: java, sockets, ssl

Running this code:

```
package test;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLServerSocket;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLServerSocketFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;

public final class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "D:\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\test\\test.store");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "123456");

        Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().execute(new Server(1));
        Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().execute(new Client("localhost", 1));
    }
}

class Server implements Runnable {

    private int port;

    public Server(int port) {
        this.port = port;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try (SSLServerSocket sslServerSocket = (SSLServerSocket) SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault().createServerSocket(port); Socket socket = sslServerSocket.accept(); InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream(); Scanner scanner = new Scanner(inputStream)) {
            System.out.println("Server: " + String.join(", ", sslServerSocket.getEnabledCipherSuites()));
            System.out.println("Server: " + String.join(", ", sslServerSocket.getEnabledProtocols()));

            if (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
            } else {
                System.out.println("No next line!");
            }
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

class Client implements Runnable {

    private String host;
    private int port;

    public Client(String host, int port) {
        this.host = host;
        this.port = port;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try (SSLSocket sslSocket = (SSLSocket) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault().createSocket(host, port); OutputStream outputStream = sslSocket.getOutputStream(); PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(outputStream)) {
            System.out.println("Client: " + String.join(", ", sslSocket.getEnabledCipherSuites()));
            System.out.println("Client: " + String.join(", ", sslSocket.getEnabledProtocols()));

            sslSocket.startHandshake();

            printWriter.println("A next line!");
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

... I am always getting this output:

```
Server: TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV
Client: TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV
Server: TLSv1.3, TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1, SSLv2Hello
Client: TLSv1.3, TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1
No next line!
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:117)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:308)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert$AlertConsumer.consume(Alert.java:285)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:181)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:164)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1152)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1063)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:402)
    at test.Client.run(Test.java:67)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

The certificate is at the right position: D:\Documents\NetBeansProjects\test\test.store I created it with this command:`keytool -genkey -alias test -keystore test.store` I also do not understand why the exception is only thrown if I call #startHandshake(). The Javadoc states that writing or reading on the socket will also start the handshake. But if I remove #startHandshake(), there is not an exception anymore  but the Server does not print the received message as well.

I use Java 11.

How can I fix this?

Comment: You should probably try `turstStorePassword` instead of `keyStorePassword. Also, you don't need to use `startHandshake` explicitly on the client.

Comment: Using `trustStorePassword` does not fix the issue. I use `startHandshake` as that way, only an exception is thrown. If I do not use it, exactly the same happens (no data is received/mabye the data is not even sent) but there is not an exception. I thought the exception could be helpful to fix the issue.

Comment: Sorry about my previous comment, I should have said "You should probably try `keyStore` instead of `trustStore`" (regarding mismatch between the two options). The server would need a keystore, the truststore is only useful on the server if you want to use client-cert authentication. You don't need `startHandshake` explicitly, since the handshake will automatically happen when you start writing to that output stream (but you may indeed get a slightly different error).

Comment: I created a .keystore file and set the property like this: `System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "D:\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\test\\test.keystore");` `System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "123456");`. I also removed the #startHandshake() call but the data is still not sent/received. The only thing which isn't there anymore is the exception.The exception is not different, it simply is not there anymore which is really strange.

Comment: I should also mention that I removed `System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "D:\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\test\\test.store");`.